# ngAnimate is not working with Angular 1.2.16

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

My problem is already stated, thus here's the plunker with the code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/p8LGG7STxjd8gFr2OJhy?p=preview

the html ROI

```
<div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="checked">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> I show up when your checkbox is checked.
</div>
```

and the css one

```
.animate-show {
-webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
transition:all linear 0.5s;
line-height:20px;
opacity:1;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid black;
background:white;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
line-height:0;
opacity:0;
padding:0 10px;
}
```

As you can see, I just took [angularJs ngAnimate doc for ngShow](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/ngShow)  and changed the plunker with angular and ngAnimate versions to match the one I am intested in.

Anyone has a tip on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you also need to add classes for `ng-hide-add-active` and `ng-hide-add-remove`:

```
.ng-hide-add-active, .ng-hide-remove {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Otherwise `ng-hide` class makes elements immediately disappear, because it has very high priority (display: none !important). Above classes cancel this behavior giving animation a chance to apply its transition rules.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8KEy5CNuEyyYrYMts9e?p=preview

Comment: Yes. I think that starting from 1.2.17 Angular handles ng-hide class properly without this extra classes.